# Mongodb embeded arrays $pull vs splice( )

Tags: mongodb

I recently had to deal with removing objects {...} from an embedded array within one my mongodb collections.

My question is, what should be the best way to remove a complex object from an embedded collection. I will go by $pull operator, i think this will be faster as well. But i know splice() will work as well. Which one should we choose and why ? comments ? suggestions please .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing elements via `update()` with the `$pull` operator is atomic.

Removing elements via sequence of `find()`, `splice()`, and `save()` calls is not atomic.

So `$pull` is both faster and deterministic, so use it whenever possible.